# Ag-grid angular format data before exporting

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have grid which I want to export:

```js
initializeColumnDefs() {
    this.columnDefs = [];
    this.columnDefs.push({
        headerName: 'time,
        field: 'completedTimestamp',
        cellRenderer: (params: any) => {
          if (params.data.isMomentarily)
            return '';
          return DatagridComponent.DefaultDatetimeCellRenderer(params);
        },
        comparator: (valueA: number, valueB: number) => {
          return DatagridComponent.DefaultDatetimeCellComparator(valueA, valueB);
        }
      },
      {
        headerName: 'people',
        field: 'people',
        cellRenderer: (params: any) => {
          if (!params || !params.value || params.value.length <= 0)
            return '';
          let titles = '';
          params.value.forEach(element => {
            if (element.name) {
              titles += element.name + ',';
            }
          });
          return titles.substring(0, titles.length - 1);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Above there's example of two columns: one with timestamp, one with object.

My `export()` method which I use to export as csv:

```
  export() {
let header = this.columnDefs.map(columnDef => {
  let id = columnDef.field || columnDef.colId || columnDef.value;
  let headerName = columnDef.headerName;
    return headerName;
  });
  let a: any;
  let params: any = {
    fileName: 'export.csv',
    columnSeparator: ';',
    skipHeader: true,
    columnKeys: this.columnDefs.map(c => c.field || c.colId).filter(c => !!c)
  };
  params.customHeader = header.join(params.columnSeparator) + '\n';
  this.grid.api.exportDataAsCsv(params);
}
```

However, I have trouble finding how format values before exporting, because here I only get header and field and no value? 
And when I export my grid to csv instead of datetime I get e.g. [image]

which is timestamp and for my object I get [image]

Instead of having `Tom, Bob, Ben`

Does anyone know how to format these values before exporting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `export()` function, you will have to add a parameter `processCellCallback`.

Something like this:

```
export() {
    let header = this.columnDefs.map(columnDef => {
      let id = columnDef.field || columnDef.colId || columnDef.value;
      let headerName = columnDef.headerName;
        return headerName;
      });
      let a: any;
      let params: any = {
        fileName: 'export.csv',
        columnSeparator: ';',
        skipHeader: true,
        columnKeys: this.columnDefs.map(c => c.field || c.colId).filter(c => !!c)
      };
      params.customHeader = header.join(params.columnSeparator) + '\n';
      params.processCellCallback = function(cellParams) {
             if(cellParams && cellParams.column.colId === 'yourTimestampfield') {
                     return this.formatter; //apply your timestamp formatter      
             } else if(cellParams && cellParams.column.colId === 'yourObjectfield') {
                     return this.formatter; //apply your object formatter  
             } else 
                    return cellParams.value // no formatting
          }
      this.grid.api.exportDataAsCsv(params);
    }
```

Read more in the example and docs [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/#processcellcallback).