# ag-grid csv export - formatting with processCellCallback

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to format values before exporting them to CSV. 
For this, I use the processCellCallback as shown in the Code sample.
When I include the Callback, I get empty strings instead of cell value for every cell in my ag-grid.
For this, I followed the example on the ag-grid Site https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/ and the StackOverflow article [Ag-grid angular format data before exporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145795/ag-grid-angular-format-data-before-exporting)

For debugging purpose I commented everything out except the return and included a console.log

The Cell Value is written in the log, but my export CSV has only empty columns. I remove the processCellCallback in the params the value are properly exported.

```js
ExportToCsv(gridApi: any, exportFileName: string){
    var params = {
      fileName: exportFileName
      ,columnSeparator: ';'
      ,processCellCallback: (params) => {this.processCells(params)}
    }
    gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(params);
  }
  processCells(params: any) {
    console.log(params.value);
    return params.value;
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

processCellCallback must return a string. However in your code, the anonymous function returns nothing.

Change:

```
processCellCallback: (params) => {this.processCells(params)}
```

to

```
processCellCallback: (params) => this.processCells(params)
```

or for simplicity:

```
processCellCallback: this.processCells
```